# Can i use yarn instead of npm?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, zsh, npm-install, yarnpkg

I'm super new to node and coding in general so please forgive me. I am trying to use [weld scraping service](https://github.com/weld-io/scraping-service), but I am using npm. To run, it says to use a yarn command: `yarn dev # development` . Is there a way I can run the same command with npm? I tried `npm install dev # development`, but it threw an error for the `#`. I tried downloading the contents of the repository first and then running, and got the same result. I tried researching what `#` means in yarn, or in terminal, and the only thing I found is in a shell script it shows that you are the superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Yarn is a package manager created by Facebook as an alternative to npm. It looks like the package you are trying to install can not be installed with npm. "npm install dev # development" will not work because it is not the format used by npm when you are trying to install some package. If the objective is to **scrape** a web site I recommend you to use some other popular npm packages as axios cheerio. You can use "npm install axios cheerio" to use them.

Answer (score 4):

...Yarn can consume the same package.json format as npm, and can install any package from the npm registry.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/